# Split Domain on different assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, assemblies

I want to ask: is it good to split domain on different assemblies?
For example, I have two entities User and Equipment, these entities not related earch other.
Is it good to have two domain assembly(for User and Equipment) and store these in different databases?
And if my application connects to different databases, should entities in different databases be in different domain assemblies?
Please explain your answer!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is your domain model should be ignorant of the persistence layer. Your application connecting to different or multiple databases should not influence your domain model or its rules as it defeats the purpose of using DDD.

You split assemblies based on your deployment pattern. You can have your domain model and persistence infrastructure in same assembly and still maintain separation of concerns. Logical decoupling is the only thing matters.

Answer (score 0):

The spliting approach does help for dependence management but not neccessary.

The granularity of dependence management dictates the cost. It would be much lower if we could manage it at a coarser level. The approach actually guides the team **not** to relate User with Equipment. **But does the cost worth the gain?** This depends on your project and team.

The same goes with splitting databases. It's unlikely that team would relate T_USER with T_EQUIPMENT. They have to use dblink or grant which is easy to find and review.

Bye the way, this approach is generic, not ddd specific.